# Windows File Sharing from a non-Domain server to AD-connected PC's

Tags: file-sharing, windows-server, workgroup

We have a few Windows Servers in our lab, and occasionally need to connect to them from our office PC's.  The lab servers are part of a Workgroup, not a Domain, but the office PC's are all part of an AD Domain.

I can turn on File Sharing on the lab servers, and I have the Sharing Permission set to "Everyone" (read access).  However, in order to connect to the server's share from an office PC, the user must provide credentials.  Since the server is not part of the domain, the user must know a set of local credentials on that server.

We'd rather not setup 1 or more extra local accounts for users, nor share the credentials for the "real" local accounts on that servers.  Is there any way to allow real public (non-credentialled) browsing of a fileshare in this config?

Comment: "Everyone" in the context of the file share is all users on the File Share not unknown users it doesn't even know about.  You might consider just connecting the file share to the domain to avoid that need.

Comment: UNIX-based SMB has a "guest" setting.  Windows File Sharing doesn't have a true guest/public mode?

Comment: Since you are on a domain you can configure the network drives for every user through a script. This requires you store the authentication details in the registry but since are sharing with all users that doesn't seem like a problem.

Comment: Windows is attempting to respect the permissions of the file permissions from another Windows installation.  You would have to have no file ownership to do this on the Windows side of the house.  Look into just mounting the share drive for the users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is done with two Local Security Policy (`gpedit.msc`) changes on the server. Both are located in:

`Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options`

`Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only = DISABLED`

`Network Access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users = ENABLED`

Do a `gpupdate /force` and try again. If it doesn't work, try rebooting the server, I'm not sure if that is required.

Long story short, "Everyone" only includes "Authenticated Users." When connecting without a username / password you are using Anonymous. You also can't access resources over the network without a password by default unless you allow blank passwords. Keep in mind both of these options greatly reduce your security on the server, but because this sounds like a lab / non-production environment it doesn't sound like an issue.

Comment: Sounded like just the thing, but I still can't get the domain-based PC's to connect to these lab servers (after making the changes, and rebooting) without being prompted for credentials.

Comment: This put me on the right track.  Found another article (http://nikolar.com/2015/03/10/creating-network-share-with-anonymous-access/) that also recommends another Local Security Policy in the same place as this Answer.  Setting "Accounts: Guest Account Status" to Enabled seems to be doing the trick so far...

Comment: I had to set the "Accounts" policy in the Answer, and the one in my Comment just above, and this enabled it for me.  I didn't need to set the "Network Access" policy.  Had to play some other games w/ Everyone permissions on the Share and on the folder, but then it worked.  Thanks!